# C# How can I get masked password from textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've set property of my textbox1 with PasswordChar = '*' and textbox display correct text that is ****.

But when I want to use that masked text (****) by set label1.text = textbox1.text, why label1.text show plain password text which not masked and how can I get masked text from my textbox1?

Comment: The password masking is a display feature of the text box, it's not a property of the password string itself. -- What would be the point of showing a label with just a star string in it anyway?

Comment: Why do you want to access masked password from server side?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Due to my application design, first run it show label text and hide textbox behind, user have to double click that label for edit data in textbox.

Comment: If you have access to Javascript or query, can you not just get the value of the input box?

Comment: @JamesS Sorry not to told you before, I've use Winform.

Comment: @savek - your comment to '500 - Internal Server Error' conflicts with what you've written in the question. Your saying in the question that the textbox string is getting masked and then setting the label, which is displayed it. However, in your comment you're saying the user double clicks the label, which then enables them to edit a textbox. Very different functionality. What should your label and your textbox contain and what should they do?

Comment: Why do you want to change the label text to the password text?

Comment: @sr28 Sorry for my bad English communication, textbox easy to edit and I think use can easily made it incorrect by inattentive, so when it show this config screen first time I hide textbox behind. When user want to edit data in this config screen, they have to double click on label for edit data.

Comment: You can simply set: `label1.Text = new string(textBox1.PasswordChar, textBox1.TextLength);`. Works even if you have set `textBox1.UseSystemPasswordChar = true`

Comment: @Jimi Thanks Jimi, and I've end up with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

To use a TextBox for passwords, just set the PasswordChar value to anything other than NULL and it will automatically hide the characters typed.

This is purely for display purposes and so if you copy the text elsewhere it won't be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Then you should customize the label to display text as masked and you should extended PasswordChar property to label.